# Язык С: можно ли вернуть функцию из другой функции?

Tags: c, функции, функциональное-программирование

В С++ этот вопрос решается возвращением функционального объекта с перегруженным оператором ().

Можно ли в чистом си сделать так, чтобы функция в виде своего результата возвращала другую функцию, что-то на подобии этого:

```
void (*message) (void) function(int args) {
  return void (*newMessage) (void);  
}
```

Или еще проще:

```
message function(int args) {
  return void (*newMessage) (void);  
}
```

Comment: Конечно, можно. См., например, [man dlsym](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если каррирование не требуется, то вот так: https://ideone.com/iDYh9y

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*func_int_int)(int);

int sqr(int x)
{
  return x * x;
}

func_int_int get_f()
{
  return sqr;
}

int main(void)
{
  func_int_int f = get_f();

  int x = f(8);
  printf("%d", x);

  return 0;
}
```

Или без typedef: https://ideone.com/LlJKT8

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sqr(int x)
{
  return x * x;
}

int (*get_f())(int)
{
  return sqr;
}

int main(void)
{
  int (*f)(int) = get_f();

  int x = f(8);
  printf("%d", x);

  return 0;
}
```

PS: Как присобачить каррирование, не знаю.

Comment: ***`"Каррирование"`*** - это что за зверь такой?

Comment: @avp, [википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) и мой примерчик на плюсах: https://ideone.com/Qujst8. Как такое сделать на си без плюсов - не представляю. Ну и [`std::bind`](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) туда же.

Comment: Понятно. Похоже на overloading. Очень надеюсь, что столь запутывающие код контекстнозависимые вещи на Си не реализуются

Comment: @avp, каким боком тут overloading?

Comment: Тем, что вредная (но весьма популярная) штука. Видим в коде одно, а в реализации оказывается другим.

Comment: @avp, ну теоретически я могу добыть rwx-кусок памяти, бинарным кодом запихать туда нужный мне вызов и отдать указатель на него как указатель на функцию. Прокатить должно, но только это утечка памяти, а ещё в си вроде нет кроссплатформенных средств получить именно rwx-память. А сама штука вроде довольно полезная - не понимаю, чем она тебе не угодила.

Answer (score 3):

Можно вернуть указатель на функцию (в С++ это тоже работает):

```
void a() {}

// Вариант 1
void (*b(int args))()
{
    (void)args;
    return a;
}

// Вариант 2
typedef void func_t();
func_t *c(int args)
{
    (void)args;
    return a;
}

// Вариант 3
typedef void (*func_t2)();
func_t2 d(int args)
{
    (void)args;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Интересно, а каррирование автору надо или нет?)

Comment: @Qwertiy про карирование я узнал только сейчас. Про него так же хотелось бы спросить.

Comment: @zurn, у меня нет ни малейшей идеи, как это можно было бы сделать в си. За счёт времени жизни переменной получается, что аргумент должен быть частью возвращаемого значения. В плюсах - это поле класса, потому и работает. А вот в си уже вряд ли получится. Ну или надо возвращать структуру с метолдом call, но это уже немного не то, чего хотелось бы? Или пойдёт?

Comment: @Qwertiy скорее всего пойдет, главное, это ведь чтобы работало именно так как нужно.

Comment: @zurn, что-то не хочет получаться...