# Язык Си: реализация каррирования

Tags: c, функции, функциональное-программирование

Каррирование, это преобразование функции от многих аргументов в набор функций, каждая из которых является функцией от одного аргумента. Вот [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) статья в Википедии.

Как вернуть функцию из другой функции на чистом Си мне уже ответили [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110010/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%A1-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8), но возможно ли подобным образом сделать каррирование?

Comment: Наверное надо вернуть массив указателей на функции

Answer (score -1):

Пример каррирования суммы. Первая строчка самая трудная (читается по спирали).

```
int (*sum (int x)) (int y)
{
    int sum1 (int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
    return sum1;
}

int main (void)
{
    return sum (12) (13);
}
```

Comment: Этот код вообще не рабочий, так как определения функций не могут быть вложенными.

Answer (score -1):

В *Си++* такое уже сотворили в виде лямбда функции. Берётся один аргумент, и создаётся функциональный объект, который будет вычислять функцию от остальных аргументов.

```
int x = 7 ;
auto f = [ x ] ( int y ) { return x * y ; } ;
```

`f` - это лямбда замыкание, где переменная `x` фиксируется, а `f` может вычислять функции с остальным аргументом `y`.

В *Си* руками это лямбда замыкание можно сотворить самому. А каррирование это всего-лишь массив таких лямбд.

```
# include <stdio.h>
typedef struct szamok zamok ;
typedef int funt ( zamok * , int ) ;

struct szamok {
  int x ;
  funt * f ;
} ;

static  int funmul ( zamok * z , int y ) {
  return z -> x * y ;
}

void callfun ( zamok * z , int y ) {
  printf ( "x = %d : " , z -> x ) ;
  printf ( "y = %d : " , y ) ;
  int r = z -> f ( z , y ) ;
  printf ( "r = %d\n" , r ) ;
}

int main ( ) {
  // создание массива с разными x 
  // и можно с разными функциями
  zamok za [ 12 ] ;
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < 12 ; ++ i )
    za [ i ] = ( zamok ) { .x = i , .f = & funmul } ;
  // --- где-то далеко вызовы
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < 12 ; ++ i )
    callfun ( & za [ i ] , i ) ;
}
```

проверка :

```
x = 0 : y = 0 : r = 0
x = 1 : y = 1 : r = 1
x = 2 : y = 2 : r = 4
x = 3 : y = 3 : r = 9
x = 4 : y = 4 : r = 16
x = 5 : y = 5 : r = 25
x = 6 : y = 6 : r = 36
x = 7 : y = 7 : r = 49
x = 8 : y = 8 : r = 64
x = 9 : y = 9 : r = 81
x = 10 : y = 10 : r = 100
x = 11 : y = 11 : r = 121
```